# RespondsToSelector returning a false-negative?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm currently using `-respondsToSelector:` like so:

```
if (![moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(currentPlaybackTime)]) {
    NSLog(@"Cannot get current playbackTime on %@", moviePlayer);
    return;
}
```

where moviePlayer is an instantiated MPMoviePlayerController object. I do a lot of other similar selector checks, so I know that pretty much everything else is working fine, but for some reason, this respondsToSelector check returns false, even though if I do something like `time = [moviePlayer currentPlaybackTime]`, it works fine. This is on 4.0+ iOS, so there's no reason for it to return false.

Any reasons why this would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>According to the iOS class reference, `currentPlaybackTime` is a property of `MPMusicPlayerController`, not `MPMoviePlayerController`.</strike>

MPMusicPlayerController:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

MPMoviePlayerController:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html

It may be a private property of `MPMoviePlayerController` that does not have an accessor.

**EDIT** (see comments)

Determine OS version:

```
float iPhoneOSVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

if ( iPhoneOSVersion < 3.2 )
{

}
else
{

}
```

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController also conforms to the MPMediaPlayback protocol as of 3.2. CurrentPlaybackTime is a required property in that protocol, meaning that MPMoviePlayerController must implement those methods from 3.2 onwards. All in all, currentPlaybackTime is a public property, that does have an accessor (which is simply -currentPlaybackTime). It also doesn't really matter if it's documented or not; [moviePlayer currentPlaybackTime] does respond with a valid return value, yet respondsToSelector for that selector returns NO. It being documented doesn't change whether it's implemented or not.

Comment: I'm surprised Apple didn't publish that protocol conformation in the MPMoviePlayerController class reference. One question - why are you checking `respondsToSelector` if that instance conforms to that protocol?

Comment: Yeah, it's really weird. It is, however, in the public .h file for MPMoviePlayerController. I'm checking respondsToSelector because it's a method that only became available from 3.2 onwards. My app supports down to 3.0, so I have to check it in order to avoid run-time exceptions.

Comment: See my edit. (Code is easier to read above.) You can determine the OS version before executing OS-specific code.